# Spring boot Kafka cannot use ContainerCustomizer to set authExceptionRetryInterval

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I would like to set [`authExceptionRetryInterval`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConsumerProperties.html#setAuthExceptionRetryInterval(java.time.Duration)) to some value so that my kafka listener is not destroyed on random auth failures.

I have a simple listener class :

```
@Component
class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${topic}")
    void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, Message> record) {
       System.out.println(record);
    }

}
```

And configuration which contains instance of `ContainerCustomizer` :

```
@Bean
public ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, AbstractMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> containerCustomizer() {
    return container -> {
            container.getContainerProperties().setAuthExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ofMillis(500));
    };
}
```

Spring-kafka version is 2.8.8.

However the problem is that this customizer is not even called (even though it is created in the context) and the auth exception timeout is not being set.

So the question is how to use `ContainerCustomizer` to customize needed properties or if this class is not suitable for it - how to set `authExceptionRetryInterval` in different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot does not automatically detect the customizer bean, you have to wire it into the container factory yourself.

```java
@Bean
ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> containerCustomizer(
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Message> factory) {

    ContainerCustomizer<String, Message, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Message>> cust = container -> {
        container.getContainerProperties().setAuthExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ofMillis(500));
    };
    factory.setContainerCustomizer(cust);
    return cust;
}
```